# Messup with 2D string array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I just moved recently to use java and after I learn some of the syntax I decided
to write a chess game to teach myself more.

I'm trying to create an array of array of string to store the basic view of the board, but when I print it out everything is null.

```
private String board[][] = new String[8][8];

    public Board() {
        System.out.println("created");
        for (String[] row : board) {
            for (String cell : row) {
                cell = "-";
            }
        }
        printBoard();
    }
```

It's feel like I'm messing a bit with the for each or the string concept.

Thanks in advance,

Or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use a `forech` loop to fill the array. Use a regular `for` loop instead. Change

```
for (String[] row : board) {
    for (String cell : row) {
        cell = "-";
    }
}
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
        board[i][j] = "-";
    }
}
```

The `foreach` loop **cannot modify** the elements of the iterated array.

Comment: If you take a closer look, you will see that using a *foreach* loop, you are only **modifying copies, not the real thing**.

Comment: Ho...Thank. So I can use for each loop to copy and sort of staff, but not modifie the same loop?

Comment: Yes, in deed. (I think you should accept this answer instead, **it's providing more details**)

Comment: You can, however, keep your first for-each loop and use `for(String[] row : board) for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) row[i] = "-";`

Answer (score 1):

```
cell = "-";
```

This assignment is happening to the local variable declared in the for loop.

You need to access each of the element in the array and assign the String.

```
for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<board[i].length; j++) {
        board[i][j] = "-";
    }
}
```

Here `board.length` is the number of `String[]` (rows) and `board[i].length` and number `String` in each array (column).